# How is the ungrammaticality of the following sentence explained?

Tags: syntax, english, syntax-trees, grammaticality, complement

> `Maria asked I read which book`

This sentence is ungrammatical.

1. Is this because an IP `I read` cannot be a complement or sister to a V `asked`
2. Is there a CP in this ungrammatical sentence?

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical because _asked_ is a predicate that subcategorizes for an indirect question, and indirect questions begin with the wh-expression. Stated in other terms, the predicate _asked_ takes an interrogative expression as its immediate dependent.

Comment: More simply put, the interrogative NP _which book_ was not displaced to the front of the _Wh-_complement clause; _Wh-_Movement did not take place as it should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ungrammaticality is not related to the fact that V cannot take IP as complement. This fact is evidenced by (1) and (2) (hence your first question):

(1) She wants [IP to leave] 
(2) She wants [IP him to leave]

The ungrammaticality is related to the strong wh-feature [+wh] which is left unchecked. The object *which book* of *read*, after assigned a theta-role and a case from this verb, it has to move to check another wh-feature of the complementizer CP (hence, your second question- yes there's a CP):

(3) [IP Maria [VP V asked [CP {+wh} [C ∅ [IP I read [DP which book]]]]]]

Comment: Your answer is complex and assumes a lot (e.g. _to leave_ is an IP, checking occurs, theta-role assignment occurs first). Why not just state that the interrogative predicate _asked_ subcategorizes for an indirect question?

Comment: This is the simplest way I could put it :D

Comment: @Tsutsu What do you mean  by  "unchecked" and "check"?

Comment: @V.Lydia Movement of wh-object *which book* is not vacuous, it's feature-driven. There's a feature that it checks. Features are linguistic properties of lexical items. CP (interrogative) has a wh-feature (for questions, whether direct or indirect) that must be checked. If movement does not take place, this feature gets no value and derivation crashes (ungrammaticality). Checking=valuation of a feature.